# check fields of a model to fill together in creation in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to make conditions for my model in this way (for just creation):
field A, B, C, and D fields together(not null) and Filed E, F, G, and H fields together.
So we can have

```
input=    (somthingA,somthingB,somthingC,somthingD,None,None,None,None)
```

OR

```
 input=   (None,None,None,None,somthingE,somthingF,somthingG,somthingH)
```

If I left one or more filed empty it returns an error:

```
input=(somthingA,None,somthingC,somthingD,None,None,None,None)
```

**error: field B can not be empty in condition 1**

Answer (score 0):

You can add this condition to your model [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.A and self.B and self.C and self.D) and not (self.E and self.F and self.G and self.H):
            raise ValidationError("Fields A, B, C, D or fields E, F, G, H must be filled together.")
        if (self.A or self.B or self.C or self.D) and (self.E or self.F or self.G or self.H):
            raise ValidationError("Fields A, B, C, D cannot be filled together with fields E, F, G, H.")
```